# Commutativity of two endomorphims

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ and $g$ be two endomorphisms of a real vector space $E$.
I want to show that if $\ker(g)$ is stabilized by $f$ then $f\circ g=g\circ f$.
Thank you for any hint.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What does it mean for $\ker g$ to be stabilized by $f$?

Comment: It means that if $x\in \ker g$ then also $f(x)\in \ker g$

Comment: It's not true, there must be further conditions. $$f \hat{=} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix};\qquad g \hat{=} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: palio: So what are the missing conditions?

Comment: Isn't your question the reverse direction, that if $f$ and $g$ commutes, then $ker(g)$ is stabilised by $f$ ?

Comment: @MattN. If we write $E=\ker g \oplus H$ where $H$ is a complementary subspace of $\ker g$ in $E$. Then $x=x_1+x_2$ hence since $\ker g$ is stabilised by $f$ then $g\circ f(x)=gof(x_2)$ and $f\circ g(x)=f\circ g(x_2)$. Hence it suffice to show that $f$ and $g$ commute on $H$. But i don't see how to go further.